# rails best_in_place turbolinks issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, best-in-place

I'm using the `best_in_place` gem with Rails 4. Code is below:

```
<p><%= best_in_place @link, :description, :classes => "summary" ,  :activator => "#edit_summary", :type => 'textarea', :nil => "<span class='none-yet'>There is no summary for this article. Would you like to create one?</span>" %></p>
<a href="#" id="edit_summary">Edit Summary</a>
```

For some reason the link doesn't open the textarea unless you refresh the page. I'm guessing it's a turbolinks issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried without turbolinks? it's fairly easy to check if that is the problem. if everything works fine without them, try the [jquery turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem. it will make things work better.